# Switch on -> Notification on. Notification off -> Switch must be off

Tags: android, service, notifications

I have an activity (say....MainActivity.java). In that activity, I have a switch. When I turn on that switch, it'll launch a service and a notification. In that notification I addAction() so that I can kill the service via notification and of course my switch MUST BE TURNED OFF.

My Solution: I create an interface (named IServiceKilled) and let my MainActivity implement it. So when the service is killed, my switch will be off too. My code:

**MainActivity.java**

```
     public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements IServiceKilled
     {
        //start service and let my activity implement the interface
        startService(new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                            AppLaunchCheckService.class));
        AppLaunchCheckService.mServiceKilled = MainActivity.this;
     ........
     @Override
     public void onServiceKilled() {
       //service is killed, switch should be off too
       swtCheck.setChecked(false);
     }
    }
```

**AppLaunchCheckService**

```
    public static IServiceKilled mServiceKilled = null;
    ......
   @Override
   public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (mServiceKilled != null) {
        mServiceKilled.onServiceKilled();
        mServiceKilled=null;
    }        
}
```

What I did above works really well! No problem with that! Now I have a BroadcastReceiver that listens for Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED and launches the service. ***NOW HERE'S COME THE PROBLEM!!!!!!!***  how can I put AppLaunchCheckService.mServiceKilled = MainActivity.this; in the receiver so that the switch will be off when it should be. Here's my broadcast receiver:

**MyTestingBroadcastReceiver**

```
    @Override
public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
  String action = intent.getAction();
  if (action != null) {
     .......
      else if (action.equals(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)) {
          context.startService(new Intent(context,
                        AppLaunchCheckService.class));
          AppLaunchCheckService.mServiceKilled = MainActivity.this;// error here
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Your MainActivity implements `IServiceKilled`. So MainActivity.this won't work in  broadcast receiver.

Comment: Yeah I know. But I want when the service is killed, the switch (in MainActivity) must be off so that users won't be confused. Maybe I should do this in another way... still hope someone could me some hints :(